# How can we remove duplicate rows in sybase IQ?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I have a table and it hasn't id column. how can i remove duplicate rows?

I have tried this one:

```
 with cte(rwn,name, lastname,dt) as(
              select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name, lastname,dt order by name) as rwn,name, lastname,dt from duplicateRowDelete
             )
  delete cte where  cte.rwn <> 1
```

It throws an error: SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'delete' on line 4

Answer (score 0):

If Sybase IQ doesn't support updatable CTEs or subqueries, then this is difficult.  One method is to recreate the table.  I think this will work:

```
select *
into #tempt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, lastname, dt order by name) as seqnum
      from duplicateRowDelete
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;

truncate table duplicateRowDelete;

insert into duplicateRowDelete(name, lastname, dt, . . .)
    select name, lastname, dt, . . .
    from #tempt;
```

This has the advantage of being faster as well -- if you need to delete a significant portion of the table.

Comment: I should not delete table.

Comment: @SelçukKılınç . . . This does not delete the table.  It empties it and reloads it.

Comment: fairly dangerous a) placing all of the good rows in a #temp table (which disappears if you lose your connection), b) wiping out the contents of the original table without 100% guarantee that you can get the original/good rows back, and c) performing all of this work outside of a transaction (again, risking loss of all data with this design)

Comment: @markp . . . The OP is free to use a regular table as well.  The idea is really the same.